# Generating Xpath Dynamically in Dynamic Table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a table with n number rows and 5 column called `EG:-ID NAME LASTNAME AND ADDRESS PHONENUMBER`
This table has pagination when ever I insert a new value the table will increase

```
ID  NAME       LASTNAME       ADDRESS         PHONENUMBER      Actions
1   Chetan     Pujari          INDIA           +91             View Details  
2   Vivek      Rajdhan         INDIA           +91             View Details
3   Sohail     Ahmed           INDIA           +91             view Details
```

I am able to view details of all the Employee. View Details id is Dynamically Generating when I Add a new Row

```
ID  NAME       LASTNAME       ADDRESS         PHONENUMBER      Actions
1   Siddu      ANup            India           +91             View Details
2   Chetan     Pujari          INDIA           +91             View Details  
3   Vivek      Rajdhan         INDIA           +91             View Details
4   Sohail     Ahmed           INDIA           +91             view Details
```

When I Click On the new View Details it is using The Old Xpath and taking to INVALID Employee VIEW DETAILS.

Comment: can you provide your HTML snippet, where the id is getting generated dynamically with the old ones.

Comment: Sorry,I Dont Have The HTML Snippet Its on Server

Comment: i am Attaching a screen Shot @ this link http://www.mindssolvit.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/test.png

Comment: Firstly you need to define who is VALID employee. It's located xth row of the table. Then you need to click its 6th td. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("tr[" + x + "]/td[5]/a")).click();` You may need to create a function to find x.

Comment: Whats the xpath u r trying?

Comment: This iS the Xapth I am Trying driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/section/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/form[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2](text(), 'gulbargatestautomation')][last()]")).click();

Comment: @Turcia I ll Try That is there any other way

Comment: can u try with `//tr[contains(.,'Siddu')]/td[last()]/select` assuming view details is under Select tag. And then perform selectByVisibleText etc. But it would help us to help u only if u provide html source of your table.

Comment: @VivekSingh Thank You for helping me out it worked for me i used like this driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/section/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/form[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[contains(.,'gulbargatestautomation')]/td[8]/div/div[1]/a/span")).click();

Comment: @chaitanyapujari cool...but try to use dynamic xpaths rather than absolute xpaths.